# SQL query inside a loop in a loop

Tags: php, sql

Hey everybody. I am trying to print out a schedule with thirty minute intervals and would like to query a DB to get whatever thing is happening at that time. If i manually enter the time (hour, minute, am/pm(months, year, day work as is)) i get events. It's just when i let the query pull the time from the loop this doesnt work. Any ideas?

```
$day = date('d');
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$start = mktime(0,0,0);


$thing_query="SELECT thing FROM things WHERE day='$day' AND month='$month' AND year='$year' AND hour='$hour' AND minute='$minute' AND ampm='$am'";


$result=mysql_query($thing_query);

for($min = 0; $min < 24 * 60 * 60; $min += 30 * 60)
{
    $hour=date("h", $start + $min);
    $minute=date("i", $start + $min);
    $am=date("A", $start + $min);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $thing = $row[0];
}

   printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>$thing</td></tr>",
          date("g:i a", $start + $min));


}
```

Comment: Why don't you query the database for everything happening in that one day, iterate through each 30 minute interval and if there's an event at that time show it. This would eliminate constantly sending a query for each interval.

Comment: BTW: Never put variables inside a printf string. The variable could contain a '%' character, and the printf might fail miserably.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine this is because you are not setting hour minute and ampm before you query the database.

You probably need to requery the DB every cycle through the loop with the new hour, minute etc, however there is probably a more efficient way of doing this... i.e. Hit the db once for the whole days data, then use PHP to iterate out the info. 1 db call insted of 24*60*60

The below code is untested so please call me up on it if it doesn't work entirely but it should give you an idea:

```
$day = date('d');
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$start = mktime(0,0,0);



$thing_query="SELECT thing FROM things WHERE day='$day' AND month='$month' AND year='$year';


$result=mysql_query($thing_query);


    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Loop through your hours mins etc and output desired values
}



}
```

All the data you need is stored in `mysql_fetch_array($result)` you can then loop through that where required. You dont want to be hitting the DB more than is necessary.

From what i can see you have the PHP to be able to do it - i think its a structure thing you are struggling with.

Comment: The query is returning undefined $thing because $hour $minute and $am are blank. I don't think i have enough PHP skills to know how to store the data, proccess, and echo out with the correct time of the for loop?

Comment: I have updated by answer above to illustrate roughly what i was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop structure is wrong - you are consuming the entirety of the query result set on your first run around the parent `for` loop. And your internal `while` loop is simply setting `$thing` to the value of one field repeatedly, so $thing ends up being the LAST value returned from the query.

comment followup. An inefficient method of doing what you want would be:

```
$day = ...
$year = ...
$month = ...
$start = ...

for ($min = 0; ....) {
   $hour = ...
   $min = ...
   $am = ...

   $thing_query = "SELECT ...."
   $result = mysql_query($thing_query) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      printf(.... $row[0] ... );
   }
}
```

But this would run a query for every single time point you're checking for. Why not just  store the event's date/time in a single date/time field. YOu can reduce your query to

```
SELECT ... WHERE timestampfield BETWEEN startdatetime AND enddatetime
```

then use the results of that in PHP to build up your events. A single "larger" query would be more efficient than a long series of "small" ones.

Comment: what should my loop structure look like? I thought that laid out the way it is it would re-query with the new hour and minute each time through?

Comment: No. You built and executed your query outside the loop. Once the query's fired off, PHP can't modify the date/time values you inserted into it.

Comment: I tried placing the query inside the for loop originally and got the same result? I've tried this a million different ways and keep ending up with nada.

Comment: It's not just executing the query within the string, you have build the query string within the loop in the first place. Once those date/time values are inserted into the string, that string WILL NOT CHANGE even if you later change the variables from which the string was built.

Answer (score 1):

Variable references in a string are only valid at assignment; they don't continue to update if you change those variables, so when you do

```
$thing_query="SELECT thing FROM things WHERE day='$day' AND month='$month' AND year='$year' AND hour='$hour' AND minute='$minute' AND ampm='$am'";
```

it's equivilent to

```
$thing_query="SELECT thing FROM things WHERE day='15' AND month='2' AND year='2011' AND hour='' AND minute='' AND ampm=''";
```

because $hour, $minute and $am haven't been set, and thus the query returns nothing.

Even if they were, updating the string won't update the database query; you'll need to call mysql_query() on the new string to get that data.

If you move the $thing_query= and $res= lines to just before the while loop this should work, although it will only return the last event in each timeslot, because you're overriding $thing each time you go through the loop. It will also continue to list an event in every timeslot until it reaches a new one, because you're not clearing $thing.

As Andy says, this isn't currently a very efficient way to do what you want, but since you're presumably just starting out I'm guessing its more important to you for now that it works rather than being efficient, so hopefully this helps for now.

Comment: You're right moving the lines did produce results and i am just starting out, but i really would like to learn the correct way of doing this. Would you mind explaining the correct efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up the order of your statements pretty badly. Here's the right way, and some additional comments:

```
$day = date('d');
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');
$start = mktime(0,0,0);



for($min = 0; $min < 24 * 60 * 60; $min += 30 * 60)
{
    $hour=date("h", $start + $min);
    $minute=date("i", $start + $min);
    $am=date("A", $start + $min);

    // you must set the string after $hour/$minute/$date have the right value
    $thing_query="SELECT thing FROM things WHERE day='$day' AND month='$month' AND year='$year' AND hour='$hour' AND minute='$minute' AND ampm='$am'";

    // query the database with the string
    $result=mysql_query($thing_query);

    // put things in an array
    $things = array();
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $things[] = $row[0];
    }

   // join the array so I have a comma separated list of things
   $listOfThings = implode(", ", $things);

   // ALWAYS use htmlspecialchars when sending data from the database to the browser!!!!
   echo "<tr><td>" . date("g:i a", $start + $min) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars($listOfThings) . "</td></tr>";


}
```

Comment: Thanks everybody for all of the help! This is by far the best group i've worked with. This solution is working great. Looks like i'm off to php.net to better understand this.